# JAVA program bug when populating array from different array

Tags: java, arrays, list, int, populate

When population oddList, evenList and negativeList from the inputList the program only populates it with one int instead of all corresponding ints from the inputList array. The output should be a list from each array whose numbers correspond to its title. The numbers are input by user into inputList array and then from there it determines whether it is odd, even, and negative and then fills the corresponding arrays.
I.E. evenList is filled with even ints from inputList.

public class ProjectTenOne 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] inputList = new int[10];
    int[] oddList = null;
    int[] evenList = null;
    int[] negativeList = null;
    int evenCount = 0;
    int oddCount  = 0;
    int negCount  = 0;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //System.out.println("Enter any ten integers: ");

    for(int list = 0; list < inputList.length; list++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter any " + (inputList.length - list) +  " integers: ");
        inputList[list] = input.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The numbers you entered: ");

    for(int in = 0; in < inputList.length; in++)
    {
        System.out.println(inputList[in]);
    }


    for(int ls = 0; ls< inputList.length; ls++)
    {
        if(inputList[ls] % 2 == 0)
        {
            evenCount = evenCount +1;
        }
        if(inputList[ls] % 2 != 0)
        {
            oddCount = oddCount +1;
        }
        if(inputList[ls] < 0)
        {
            negCount = negCount +1;
        }
    }

    evenList     = new int[evenCount];
    oddList      = new int[oddCount];
    negativeList = new int[negCount];

    for(int l = 0; l < inputList.length; l++)
    {
        if((inputList[l] % 2) == 0)
        {   
            for(int j = 0; j < evenList.length; j++)
            {
                evenList[j] = inputList[l];

            }
        }
        if((inputList[l] % 2) != 0)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < oddList.length; k++)
            {
                oddList[k] = inputList[l];

            }
        }
        if(inputList[l] < 0)
        {
            for(int h = 0; h < negativeList.length; h++)
            {
                negativeList[h] = inputList[l];

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The ODD List is: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < oddList.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(oddList[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("The EVEN List is: ");
    for(int j = 0; j < evenList.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(evenList[j]);
    }

    System.out.println("The NEGATIVE List is: ");
    for(int k = 0; k < oddList.length; k++)
    {
        System.out.println(negativeList[k]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take evenList as the example here, but the same applies to the other two arrays as well.

In your code, you iterate over your inputList and check for an even number. If it is even, you set the entire evenList array to the found value, instead of just a single element.

You can solve this problem by declaring an int outside of your outer loop that keeps track of the number of even numbers entered. As an example:

```
int evenIndex = 0;
for(int l = 0; l < inputList.length; l++)
{
    if((inputList[l] % 2) == 0)
    {
        evenList[evenIndex++] = inputList[l];
    }
    /*Other code*/
}
```

You also made a mistake in your last loop. You iterate over negativeList, but you use the size of evenList. This will result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when negativeList is smaller than evenList.